# Can't get to the DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, raty

I got voting script on my page (jQuery Raty), everything work's fine but I want to change rate number in my ajax after voting.

Have problem with getting to span class .glosy

My html:

```
<div class=\"movie__rate\">
    <div class=\"score\" data-score=\"$czy_glosowal2[ocena]\" data-user=\"$stat[id]\" data-movie=\"$podobny_film[id]\"></div>
    <span class=\"movie__rate-number\">
        <span class=\"glosy\">170</span>
    głosów</span>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
('.score').raty({

click: function(score) {

var licznik_komentarzy = $(this).find('.glosy').text();
var zapisanie_licznika = $(this).find('.glosy').val(licznik_komentarzy);
var dodanie_licznika = +$(this).find('.glosy').val() + 1;                   
$(this).find('.glosy').text(dodanie_licznika);
            }               
            });
```

tried different methods (next(), nextAll(), find()) and still cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `this` is actually the element (depends on how plugin is written) ... you are looking in the wrong direction in the DOM tree.

`closest()` looks up the tree for ancestors.

You would need to use `find()` to look for a descendant of `.score`

Comment: what is `this`? log it to console

Comment: just noticed, since your html wasn't formatted I misread it,  is actually a sibling  ... if `this` is the element, try `siblings()`

Comment: parent = div .score,  first child = NULL. Dont know where to check this in log.

Comment: also can't use `val()` on anything but a form control.

Comment: Yep, but it works for me with (.score) but then it change me all (.score) at page, so I need to get to This element.

Comment: can initialize plugin from inside an `each` loop. Then store variable of $(this)` and use that inside the `click`